# Email notification from R programming (R code runs successfully or fails)

Tags: r, rscript

I pulling data from JSON API, sometimes it fails and returns http code not equal to "200" [status_code="200" means connection was successful]

```
Get_data<- GET(URL,authentication("abs@def.com","password"))
Get_code<- status_code(Get_data)
```

If Get_code=200; it means the Get_data worked well.
**So here, I need help with:
If Get_code="200" then I need to send an email with message as "Connection is successful" else "Connection declined"**

I tried using R packages like: mail, mailR, sendmailR but could not create the desired code. please direct us with your inputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried `mailR` and that didn't work, I advise you take a look at an ifttt recipe : https://ifttt.com/

The maker channel from ifttt can take any input, including one from R. You can then set a recipe saying :

IF THIS : received an input from R in the maker channel

THEN THAT : send an email (or a push notification, or anything possible with ifttt).

You should check this blogpost to know how to connect ifttt & R : http://bconnelly.net/2015/06/connecting-r-to-everything-with-ifttt/

Best,

Colin